# Subdomain redirects to subdirectory

Tags: subdomain, subdirectory

Supposing I have folder called "support" inside root folder "/public_html". I've added a subdomain in my server's panel so that when going to "support.mydomain.com" it redirects to "mydomain.com/support"

The problem is that redirection is reflected on the browser's address bar, and I want to make that subdomain work like "base domain". i.e "support.mydomain.com/folder-inside-support"

Is it something to be with .htaccess file?

Comment: Hi @Redraw, There are many questions and answers regarding usage of redirects from and to sub domains and sub folders already on Pro Webmasters. Linked is one of many that may be what your looking for. See linked answer and change `^www\.mydomain\.com$` to something like `^support\.mydomain\.com/subfolder/$`

Comment: I answered this for you on WordPress.SE

Comment: It was marked as duplicated, however the question proposed as already answered is not the same as I was looking for. I don't care about the SEO in this case, and I need to redirect **a subdirectory to a subdomain**, not the root index page to a directory. I couldn't make it work yet. I don't know exactly where the right .htaccess file should be located. Inside the root folder? inside the subdirectory folder?